# Recover Arangodb databases from /var/lib/databases directory?

Tags: arangodb

In some beta version of Arangodb 3.4 my database crashed while I tried to add a view via arangosh. Because I were not able to start the database anymore, it was not possible to make a backup (database dump).

I just wanted to install the newest Arangodb 3.4.2.1 then, but that failed because my CPU was to old (no SSE 4.2 support). So I bought a new computer, sat up a new linux, copied the databases to /var/lib/arangodb3/databases, started a new installation of Arangodb in which it even asked me, if the current databases should be upraded. I confirmed that.

Unfortunately it hasn't found the databases in that directory, so I have now just acces to the system database.

My question is: Can I recover the databases which are laying in /var/lib/arangodb3/databases somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a copy of the "var/lib/arangodb3" directory (which includes "databases" as a subfolder) as well? If so, copy the folder to a location on your new machine where Arangodb 3.4.2.1 is installed. You also have to make sure to give the user `arangodb` access to this folder with the following command:

`chown -R arangodb:arangodb /path/to/your/arangodb3RecoveryFolder`

Next you can modify the `arangod.conf` (located at /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf) to point to your recovery arangodb3 folder.

```
[database]
directory = /path/to/your/arangodb3RecoveryFolder
```

Then stop the arangodb3 service with `sudo service arangodb3 stop`, 
run `sudo service arangodb3 upgrade` to upgrade the database directory and `sudo service arangodb3 start` to start the service again.

You can check if the service is running by executing `sudo service arangodb3 status`. In case it is not working, have a look at potential error messages in the log file (/var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log).